# Filter matching strings between two text files in Clojure

Tags: filter, clojure, compare

The text files have a list of paths with a different prefix.

Lets say before.txt looks like this:

```
before/pictures/img1.jpeg
before/pictures/img2.jpeg
before/pictures/img3.jpeg
```

and after.txt looks like this:

```
after/pictures/img1.jpeg
after/pictures/img3.jpeg
```

The function deleted-files should remove the different prefix (before, after) and compare the two files to print the missing list of after.txt.

Code so far:

```
(ns dirdiff.core
(:gen-class))

(defn deleted-files [prefix-file1 prefix-file2 file1 file2]
    (let [before (slurp "resources/davor.txt")
    (let [after (slurp "resources/danach.txt")
)
```

Expected output: which is the one who was deleted

```
/pictures/img2.jpeg
```

How can I filter the lists in clojure.clj to show only the missing ones?

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it. If you are looking for
ideas, how to start, have a look at `clojure.data/diff` or
`clojure.set`.

Comment: Please **edit your question** and tell us the results you expect for the given data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to compute a *set difference* between the two sets of filenames after prefices have been removed:

```
(defn deprefixing [prefix]
  (comp (filter #(clojure.string/starts-with? % prefix))
        (map #(subs % (count prefix)))))

(defn load-string-set [xf filename]
  (->> filename
       slurp
       clojure.string/split-lines
       (into #{} xf)))

(defn deleted-files [prefix-file1 prefix-file2 file1 file2]
  (clojure.set/difference (load-string-set (deprefixing prefix-file1) file1)
                          (load-string-set (deprefixing prefix-file2) file2)))

(deleted-files "before" "after"
               "/tmp/before.txt" "/tmp/after.txt")
;; => #{"/pictures/img2.jpeg"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would approach it, starting from [this template project](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template):

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core tupelo.test)
  (:require
    [clojure.set :as set]
    [tupelo.string :as str]
    ))

(defn file-dump->names
  [file-dump-str prefix ]
  (it-> file-dump-str
    (str/whitespace-collapse it)
    (str/split it #" ")
    (mapv #(str/replace % prefix "") it)))

(defn delta-files
  [before-files-in after-files-in
   before-prefix after-prefix]
  (let-spy [before-files     (file-dump->names before-files-in before-prefix)
            after-files      (file-dump->names after-files-in after-prefix)
            before-files-set (set before-files)
            after-files-set  (set after-files)
            delta-sorted     (vec (sort (set/difference before-files-set after-files-set)))]
    delta-sorted))
```

and a unit test to show it in action:

```
(dotest
  (let [before-files  "before/pictures/img1.jpeg
                       before/pictures/img2.jpeg
                       before/pictures/img3.jpeg "

        after-files   "after/pictures/img1.jpeg
                       after/pictures/img3.jpeg "
        before-prefix "before"
        after-prefix  "after"]
    (is= (delta-files before-files after-files before-prefix after-prefix)
      ["/pictures/img2.jpeg"])
    ))
```

Be sure to study the [these documentation sources](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template#documentation), including books like **Getting Clojure** and the **Clojure CheatSheet**.

---

Notes:

I like to use `let-spy` and `let-spy-pretty` to illustrate the progression of code.  It produces output like so:

```
-------------------------------
   Clojure 1.10.2    Java 15
-------------------------------

Testing tst.demo.core
before-files => ["/pictures/img1.jpeg" "/pictures/img2.jpeg" "/pictures/img3.jpeg"]
after-files => ["/pictures/img1.jpeg" "/pictures/img3.jpeg"]
before-files-set => #{"/pictures/img3.jpeg" "/pictures/img2.jpeg" "/pictures/img1.jpeg"}
after-files-set => #{"/pictures/img3.jpeg" "/pictures/img1.jpeg"}
delta-sorted => ["/pictures/img2.jpeg"]

Ran 2 tests containing 1 assertions.
0 failures, 0 errors.
```

The `spyx` macro is also very useful for debugging.  See [the README](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo) and [the API docs](https://cljdoc.org/d/tupelo/tupelo/CURRENT).